# Switch Network Link Conditioner profiles from console/script

Tags: macos, networking

Is it possible to switch Network Link Conditioner profiles from MacOS command line or by using script, and generally is it possible to automate NLC, if so how?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The following applescript works well in OS X El Capitan.You have to pass a system attribute:

```
set mode to system attribute "mode"
tell application "System Preferences"
activate
set current pane to pane "com.apple.Network-Link-Conditioner"
end tell

tell application "System Events"
 tell process "System Preferences"
  tell window "Network Link Conditioner"
    click button "ON"
    tell group 1
        click pop up button 1
        click menu item mode of menu 1 of pop up button 1
    end tell
  end tell
 end tell
end tell
```

Syntax to pass system attribute (from command line):

`mode=DSL osascript yourFile.applescript`

Replace DSL by network link conditioner profiles (3G, Wifi, Edge)

Comment: If I use `mode=3G osacript NLC_Guido.applescript` from terminal, I get `-bash: osacript: command not found`.

Comment: I needed to do `set current pane to pane id "com.apple.Network-Link-Conditioner"`

Answer (score 3):

The Network Link Conditioner tool is essentially a GUI to control *dummynet* rules which can be controlled on the command line using `dnctl` and `pfctl` (or `ipfw` on older versions of MacOS and BSD) as described by Jonathan Levin's informative [*OS Internals book](http://newosxbook.com/bonus/vol1ch16.html).

So instead of using NLC you could just directly use `dnctl` to create/modify rules on the command line - for some examples see the dnctl and pfctl man pages and a related [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/725030/traffic-shaping-on-osx-10-10-with-pfctl-and-dnctl).