# Throttling connection speed in Automated test in El Capitan?

Tags: python, shell, automated-tests, osx-elcapitan, packets

So I was planning on writing an automated test using python-selenium(really webdriver) that uses a [subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325463/launch-a-shell-command-with-in-a-python-script-wait-for-the-termination-and-ret) to throttle the connection speed before a suite of tests. I found this [great script](https://gist.github.com/ardell/957212) for ipfw, only to find out that OS X El Capitan switched to PF(Packet Filter) at [Yosemite](https://superuser.com/questions/905645/ipfw-not-available-on-mac-os-x-yosemite).

Everything I keep running into is obsolete. So what's the best way to throttle internet via shell or cli on El Capitan? Does anyone have a script they can share? Network Link Conditioner is great for testing but it would be great if I could start catching bugs that occur at slow speeds with automation.

Comment: Can't do it from the command line since webdriver uses up your one available `--debug` sessions, but available in Chrome's devtools as Network Connectivity Emulation. Or install NLC in a VM/container and use that.

Comment: I was looking into why a debug flag would be an issue and came across this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27881485/network-throttling-with-chrome-and-selenium, which is only an issue if I'm using dev tools to slow the connection which isn't what I was asking how to do. I was talking about slowing all traffic at a system level.  Don't think VM answers the question.  Did come across a newer script http://serverfault.com/questions/725030/traffic-shaping-on-osx-10-10-with-pfctl-and-dnctl but haven't been able to get it working on OSX 10.11.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to throttle network using network link conditioner. To install network link conditioner, you need to get Hardware IO Tools. More details are available in [Installing Apple's Network Link Conditioner Tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9659382/installing-apples-network-link-conditioner-tool)

To automate the setting of bandwidth profile in network link conditioner, you can refer my answer in [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34876073/switch-network-link-conditioner-profiles-from-console-script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38991769/3884020)

Comment: Accepted the answer because this works. But it is a bit annoying to have to use an applescript to use the GUI for NLC. If anyone finds a way to do this without using the GUI to turn on NLC profiles or throttle using Packet Filter please let us know.